# Link showing up different on iPhone then what browser tests show (including Safari)

Tags: ios, css, iphone

I've run many tests for mobile including using Google Chrome and Safari's Responsive Design mode with the iPhone 6 setting, however, a link with an icon is showing up differently on my actual iPhone 6.. does anyone know how I can get the same result on my browser so I can tweak the CSS so the icon doesn't go underneath? Thanks

This is what shows up on the tests in the browsers

[image: This is what shows up on the tests in the browsers]

This is what shows up on the actual iPhone 6..

[image: This is what shows up on the actual iPhone 6]

Comment: where is all of your code? looking at an image will not help anyone figure it out

Comment: I'm not asking for help with code. I'm asking how I can figure out why its showing up different on the iPhone browser testers, over the actual iPhone. Sending you the code won't help either.

Comment: I don;t know why

Comment: Thanks. I'm hoping someone knows a way of testing.

Comment: do you have the website live somewhere to see?